# Multiple Choice question about a continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, definite-integrals

If $f \colon \mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is a continuous function, which of the following statements implies that $f(0)=0$?

(A) $\int_0^1 f(x)^n \,dx\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$
(B) $\int_0^1 f\left(\frac xn\right) \,dx\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$
(C) $\int_0^1 f(nx) \,dx\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$
(D) $\int_0^1 f(x+n) \,dx\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$

I came across the above problem and do not know how to tackle it. Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Have you tried calculating the limiting values for each of the integrals? Pick your favourite continuous functions (I suggest $f(x)=1/2$ as a starting point) and look at what the limits are. You should be able to rule out some of the possibilities.

Comment: Some hints: (A) - Take a function such that $f(0)=1$ and $f(x)\in [0,1)$ if $x\in (0,1]$. (B),(C),(D) - Change of Variables

Comment: In fact for D there is no constraint on $f$ at any finite argument.  Let $f(x)$ be arbitrary for $x \lt 10^9$ and zero thereafter.  It meets D.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT**: upon your request, I'll add a further discussion.

I'll start with (B), which is both true and also harder than the rest of the cases. Note that after the substitution I mentioned we have
$$n \int_0^{1/n} f(x)dx.$$
Now, since $f(x)$ is continuous, we can write $|f(x) - f(0)| < \epsilon$ for every $\epsilon > 0$ as soon as $x < \delta$ for some $\delta > 0$. In particular, pick $n$ big enough, so that $1/n < \delta$. Using this we can write
$$\left|n \int_0^{1/n} \left(f(x) - f(0) \right) dx \right| 
\leq  n \int_0^{1/n} |f(x) - f(0)| dx
 \leq n {1 \over n}  \epsilon = \epsilon.$$
Therefore the limit of integrals in the OP equals $f(0)$ and in particular vanishes if and only if $f(0) = 0$.

For (C), my substitution leads to
$${1 \over n} \int_0^n f(x)dx$$
and one can think of this as an average over the integral of length $n$. Therefore for this to vanish, it's sufficient that $f(x)$ decays sufficiently quickly (for simplicity take $f(x) = e^{-x}$, but anything subconstant works as well) and so it is certainly not necessary that $f(0) = 0$.  Case (D) can be treated similarly. Again, it's enough that the function decays sufficiently quickly.

The case (A) is a little bit different but note that it's only important whether $f(x) <1$ or $f(x) > 1$ for $x \in (0,1)$ (why?).

---

For (A) take e.g. $f(x) = 1 - x$. Using this as inspiration, try to find *all* functions for which (A) fails.

For the rest of the cases, use substitutions and notice that the integrals can always be expressed in terms of the original function $f$.

(B) substitute $x = ny$;

(C) substitute $y = nx$;

(D) substitute $y = x + n$.

Comment: It is very kind of you for the detailed explanation.I have got it.Thanks a lot sir.